# getSupportActionBar() returns null and no actionbar showing in activity

Tags: android, null, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I have this weird problem with the support actionbar in android.. Here's my activity:

```
public class TicketDetails extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_BlueGrey);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ticket_details);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();//null in here 
        //some other code
   }
//some other methods
}
```

And my theme is defined like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme.BlueGrey" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue_grey_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue_grey_700</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue_grey_300</item>
</style>
```

minSdk is set to 13 and I keep getting null in there. What could be the problem? My other activities work just fine but this one has no actionbar and `getSupportActionBar` returns `null` always. Tried calling it in the onStart or onResume but still the same.
Thank you!

[EDIT] This is the list with my imports:

```
package ga.adlabs.betticket.activities;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.mikepenz.google_material_typeface_library.GoogleMaterial;
import com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable;
import com.mikepenz.iconics.typeface.FontAwesome;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import ga.adlabs.betticket.R;
import ga.adlabs.betticket.fragments.FragmentDataProviderTicketDetails;
import ga.adlabs.betticket.fragments.FragmentTicketDetails;
import ga.adlabs.betticket.workers.AbstractDataProvider;
import ga.adlabs.betticket.workers.DataProviderTicketList;
```

Comment: Are you extending the support version of action bar? What happens wen you call `getActionBar()`?

Comment: I use Actionbaractivity from the support library so I think support actionbar is there by default, right?

Comment: Make sure you are using `AppCompatActivity`, `ActionBarActivity` is deprecated.

Comment: Post all of your code, we need to see your imports.

Comment: Most likely it's because of ´AppTheme´ style extending a theme without action bar. Android doesn't support double inheritance (one from ´AppTheme.´ and second one from ´parent="´).

Comment: Made an edit with the imports.. @beworker, Doesn't AppTheme_BlueGray inherit everything from Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar ?

Comment: @csanonymus You need to say. Check out the style file to see what theme AppTheme.BlueGray inherits from.

Answer (score 1):

You might created the ActionBar with Material Design (also called with `Toolbar`). Call this code after `setContentView()` method:

```
Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar); // setting toolbar is important before calling getSupportActionBar()
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

Please learn more about [designing the app with Material Design](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/).

Comment: Yes, I know I can do that but I would keep that as a last option because my class has a lot of code in it and I want to keep everything as simple as I can.. Thanks for the suggestion though!